# ¿id incrementa a pesar de error de valor duplicado? PDO PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Buen día, estoy haciendo un formulario donde se genere un código único aparte del id, nose si es correcto, pero el problema es que cuando intento insertar un dato duplicado que tiene restricción (UNIQUE), a pesar que me arroja el error se incrementa mi id a pesar que no se ha registro, mi código es el siguiente:

```
public function insert(
    $idDigitador,
    $datoRegistro,
    $idZona,
    $datonVale,
    $datoTurno,
    $datopreImpreso,/*...*/

    )
{
    try 
    {
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Lima');
        $converdatoRegistro = date($datoRegistro.' H:i:s');
        /* Iniciar una transacción, desactivando 'autocommit' */
        $this->db->beginTransaction();
        $query = "INSERT INTO tvalexplosivos VALUES (null,
        :id_usuario, 
        :valexplosivo_fecha, 
        :id_zona, 
        :valexplosivo_nvale, 
        :valexplosivo_turno, 
        :valexplosivo_preimpresor, /*...*/
        );";
        $result = $this->db->prepare($query);
        if (!$result) {
            echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
            print_r($result->errorInfo());
        }

        $result->execute(array(
        ':id_usuario' => $idDigitador,
        ':valexplosivo_fecha' => $converdatoRegistro,
        ':id_zona' => $idZona,
        ':valexplosivo_nvale' => $datonVale,
        ':valexplosivo_turno' => $datoTurno,
        ':valexplosivo_preimpresor' => $datopreImpreso/*...*/
        ));
```

> Intente evitar con el commmit pero no me funciona

```
        $this->db->commit();/* Consignar los cambios */
        $id = $this->db->lastInsertId();
        // Obtenemos el Id (Aun falta arreglar)
        //$idResult = $this->db->lastInsertId(); 


        $rptSql = [
            "estado" => 1,
            "mensaje" => "Se registro correctamente",
            "coperacion" => $datopreImpreso,
            "id" => $id,
        ];
        return $rptSql;

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        //$this->db->rollback();
```

> Ya aqui manejo el error de que es valor duplicado

```
        if($e->getCode() == 23000){
            $messageUser = "Se duplico n° de Vale";
        }
        else{
            $messageUser = "";
        }
        $rptSql = [
            "estado" => 0,
            "messageDeveloper" => "Se encontro ERROR ".$e->getMessage(),
            "messageUser" => $messageUser,
            "codigo" => $e->getCode(),
            "string" => $e->__toString(),
        ];
        return $rptSql;
    }
    finally {
        //print_r($this->db->errorInfo());
    }
}
```

> mi codigo unique es $datopreImpreso

Como puedo evitar o solucionar el problema, gracias

Comment: Esto no es un proble es el funcionamiento normal de un autoincrementar. No debería de haber ningún problema en que los id no sean consecutivos. Si tu lógica depende de que si o si sean consecutivos, deberías manejar por ti mismo la generación asumiendo los problemas de concurrencia que puede conllevar en lugar de delegar esta tarea en algo externo como la base de datos.

Comment: pero como haría para evitarlo? tendría que obtener el id anterior y insertarlo manualmente?

Comment: Si, tendrías que obtener el último, incrementarlo e insertarlo. Sin embargo, tal como comenta @Xerif , puede conllevar ciertos problemas. La idea de tener un ID es que sea único y no que sea consecutivo, ya que es un _identificador único para cada registro_. Si requieres un consecutivo, es mejor tener un campo diferente del ID que sea UNIQUE (_así como lo tienes actualmente_) y aplicarle la lógica que ya dedujiste.

Comment: Los IDs autoincrementales se aumentan siempre, aun en las consultas fallidas. Una forma de evitarlo es verificando que no hay restricciones antes de las operaciones de inserción. Es decir, antes de insertar puedes verificar que el eventual registro pasa la restricción de duplicidad.